# Making FETCH_CLASS dynamic

Tags: php, pdo, fetch

Thanks for reading. How does one make the class name dynamic in a FETCH_CLASS query. i.e. so that this method can be called by any class...(what do you replace 'User' with)

```
  public static function find_by_sql($sql){
       global $handler;
       $query = $handler->query($sql);
       $object_array = $query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_CLASS, 'User');
       return $object_array;
       }
```

Solution (embarrassingly) is....

```
 public static function find_by_sql($sql){
    global $handler;
    $query = $handler->query($sql);
    $class = get_class($this);
    $object_array = $query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_CLASS, $class);
    return $object_array;
   }
```

Comment: with $class_name variable?

Comment: I tried $class = get_class($this) and then $object_array = $query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_CLASS, $class); but clearly my syntax is wrong...(ps I should start paying you...)

Comment: Solved.....using the above....(hmmmm)